# java.net.URL cache when reading from files

Tags: java, file, io

It seems like java is holding some kind of a cache to URL (& files).
e.g. 
I have a file "resourcs.txt" in a jar file in my classpath.
The content of this file is:
"Version 1"

```
new java.io.BufferedReader (new java.io.InputStreamReader( new URL("jar", "", "file:test.jar!/resourcs.txt").openConnection().getInputStream())).readLine()
```

returns "Version 1" (as expected)

I change the file content to be "Version 2" and call again to this code.
And I still get "Version 1"

How can I clear this "cache".

Notice: I found out it only happens on Linux.

Comment: I bet that it is more related to the fact that it is a .jar file than to using URL

Comment: I'm not sure, it only happens on Linux

Comment: Interesting. Are the first streams closed properly?

Comment: Are you swapping the jar file while your Java program is running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the `jar` protocol used in your URL, the connection is an instance of [sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/JarURLConnection.java) which takes benefit from a cache implemented in [sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/JarFileFactory.java)

Source code confirms a `setUseCache(false)` on `URLConnection` implementation will prevent the use of that cache.

My hypothesis about the Linux/Windows behavior difference: the close event notification from URLJarFileCloseController interface is triggered faster on Windows because it does not appreciate to keep file handles opened for a too long period...

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the simple answer is really close to the answer given by sbridges, but
you can't instantiate URLConnection using "new URLConnection(...)", because it's a abstract class.

You can just do this way:

```
    URL url = new URL(urlSrt);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setUseCaches(false);
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I think the resource caching in java is a dangerous feature not everyone knows about. I tried to refresh webcam images from a url but always got the same image.

Comment: I'm trying this, thought it would work but without success.  I'm baffled.  In my case, it's not a JAR url and it is also using `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off caching for a url connection using,

```
  URLConnection con = new URLConnection(new URL("jar", "", "file:test.jar!/resourcs.txt"));
  con.setUseCaches(false);
  new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())).readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is some kind of class-loading problem, because it is the jar-protocoll.

Try to open your jar as a zip-file instead.

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(file);
try {
  InputStream in = zf.getInputStream("resourcs.txt");
  // ... read from 'in' as normal
} finally {
  zf.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some third party code this should work:

```
url.openConnection().setDefaultUseCaches(false);
```